# Why is my SELECT code not working?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a program that moves registration data from one datatable to another (think login activation page from temp to permanent after email confirmation). I'm not the best at Mysql yet, still learning so it might be a stupid question. I've checked all over stackoverflow and it looks like I'm doing it correctly.

For some reason my select call is not working. Here is a bit of my code:

```
$username = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT 'username' FROM 'temp_users' WHERE 'activation'= '$key'");
$password = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT 'password' FROM 'temp_users' WHERE 'activation'= '$key'"); 


// Add row to database 
mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt', 'email') VALUES ('$username', '$password_hash', '$salt', '$email')");

echo $username, $password, $email, mysqli_affected_rows($dbc), $key;

// Print a customized message:
   if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) //if update query was successfull
     {
      echo '<div>Your account is now active. You may now <a href="login.php">Log in</a></div>';

  } else {
      echo '<div>Oops !Your account could not be activated. Please recheck the link or contact the system administrator.</div>';

        }
```

I threw in the echo my variables so I could see what was going on. At this point, $key is correct, $email is correct from earlier code, mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) is giving me a -1 (which means error). $username and $password are blank variables, so clearly I am doing the SELECT incorrectly.

Any thoughts or help?

Comment: *Simple*, it's because you're using quotes around your table names and columns; just remove them.

Comment: Gotta love the (in)consistency: `INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt', 'email'` ;)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. OP has a strange way of querying DB @TheBlueDog Didn't bother putting in an answer. I think it would have only opened up a proverbial "can of worms". OP's code is overkill and quite confusing, *at best*.

Comment: thanks everyone, I had been trying every which way with the quotes, it is still error crashing, but at least that part is right now

Comment: I don't know why you're using two seperate queries when you can do it in one go: 

`$query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT username, password FROM temp_users WHERE activation= '$key'");` then just continue on from there. @Gu3miles

Comment: I know I'm not very good at this, it's my 4th day learning :(

I'm just trying to copy what they do at w3school. If you have a better way I should be doing this would love to learn.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I have to leave in about 5-10 minutes, so I won't have time to do a rewrite. If the person below who gave you an "answer" is up to it, ask and see. If not, I'll see what I can do when I get back. @Gu3miles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `'`(Single quotes) use   (backticks) = ``

```
SELECT `username` FROM `temp_users` WHERE `activation`= '$key'
```

Comment: Don't even need backticks, unless using reserved words.

Comment: But @Fred-ii- It's good habit to use it .I'm even use it elsewhere

Comment: It's purely by preference. Some will say yes, others will say no; including some of the higher rep guys and gals on here. But I will +1 this ;-)

Comment: Hello, i figured out my problem. It was a combo of single quotes and backticks in the right location. Thanks again, it all works now